# Impala SQL - How to solve 'Subqueries in OR predicates are not supported' exception

Tags: sql, impala

For example, you have a table like below

```
ID   TaskID    TaskName   Status       CaseID   
1     1         a         completed    101
1     2         a         pending      102
1     3         b         completed    103
1     4         c         completed    104
```

If want to get output table like

```
ID TaskID TaskName Status     CaseID
1   4     c        completed  104
1   3     b        completed  103
```

you can use Impala SQL(real problem will group by ID with large volume)

```
SELECT ID, TaskID, TaskName, Status, CaseID
FROM table 
WHERE TaskID in (select MAX(TaskID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) from table)
   or TaskName = ‘b’
```

This works in MySQL, however it will get exception in Impala

```
AnalysisException: Subqueries in OR predicates are not supported
```

How to solve this OR exception issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decompose your query in 2 queries and union the results like this to avoid the restriction about subqueries in or predicates

```
SELECT ID, TaskID, TaskName, Status, CaseID
FROM table 
WHERE TaskID in (select MAX(TaskID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) from table where TaskName != 'b')
union all 
SELECT ID, TaskID, TaskName, Status, CaseID
FROM table 
WHERE TaskName = 'b'
```

Comment: Thanks, hlagos! A typo error there and fixed. You are right, I also found only this solution may solve this Impala issue

Comment: But you can use Union instead, union all will give duplicates!

Comment: your welcome! not sure how you can get duplicates if you exclude b for first result set

Comment: You are right! For this particular example, it will not get duplicates. But for large amount of data (for example table has extra columns with same current columns data, which may cause duplicate). Just wondering is that normally using Union more safe than using Union all ?

Comment: it should but also more expensive it if has to deduplicate. Depending on the size of your data it would require several networking and resources impacting the performance of your query

Comment: btw, i dont think impala support union, only union all

Comment: Hi, actually impala support union. But not sure if union in impala will remove duplicates, this need to check impala docs!

Comment: oh I see, maybe is my impala version :). thanks for sharing

Comment: Sure nws! Old impala still have lots of defects! You may need to update to latest version!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you can use `not exists` :

```
SELECT ID, TaskID, TaskName, Status, CaseID
FROM table t
WHERE Status = 'completed' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.TaskName = t.TaskName AND t1.Status = 'Pending');
```

If i go with your code, then i would rewrite it by using correlated subquery :

```
SELECT ID, TaskID, TaskName, Status, CaseID
FROM table 
WHERE TaskID = (SELECT MAX(t1.TaskID) FROM table t1 WHERE t1.TaskName = t.TaskName) OR
      TaskName = 'c';
```

Comment: Hi Yogesh, thanks for your advice. The first method you provided can deal with small amount of data. If the data complexity is getting larger, we are hardly to deal with in the opposite way. The second method will still give that Impala exception error.